# Declared 'a' in a char type variable but 'b' come as output, what is wrong?

Tags: c, casting, char

So, the goal is to put "n" letters in "n" lines, n being the iterations size. But a unexpected output appears.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    int tam;
    char letra = 'A';

    printf("Tree size?\n");
    scanf("%d", &tam);

    for (int i = 0; i < tam +1; i++){

        for (int j = 0; j < i+1; j++)
        {           
            if (j < i)
                printf("%c", letra);

        }
        letra = (char)((int)letra + 1);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The expected output:

```
 A
 BB
 CCC
 .
 .
 .
```

What i get:

```
B
CC
DDD
.
.
.
```

I tried to put another printf, if outside the output is 'a' as expected, but inside the for it corrects the letter problem and add one more line to the tree size.
Example - (tree size: 3 A BB CCC DDDD)
Whats wrong?

Comment: The first time you encounter `if (j < i)`, i and j are 0, so the condition is wrong and nothing is printed.

Comment: BTW: instead of `letra = (char)((int)letra + 1);` you can write `letra = letra + 1;`, or even `letra++`.

Comment: `if (j < i)`  --> `if (j <= i)`

Comment: interesting that worked as you said, even so i tried something similar before and gave Compiler Error C2106 the expression was (letra = letra + i), but even that are working now, strange... Anyways thanks for the feedback ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not printing first letter, by using

```
if (j < i)
```

you say:
`0 < 0`, also your tree size will be incorrect as first loop is up to `i + 1`,
here is correct code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    int tam;
    char letra = 'A';

    printf("Tree size?\n");
    scanf("%d", &tam);

    for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++, ++letra){
        for (int j = 0; j < i+1; j++)
        {           
            printf("%c\n", letra);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (j < i)` should be `if (j < i + 1)`

and the first `for` loop should be `for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++)`

See here for a working example: https://onlinegdb.com/B15_KfsRG